# Javascript is not getting implemented while running python program

Tags: javascript, python, html

**Python Code**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def button():
    return render_template("buttons.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Creating new channel</title>
    <script src="{{url_for('static', filename = 'js/button.js')}}"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="unordered"></ul>
    <form>
        <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Create Channel" autocomplete="off" />
        <button class="submit">Create Channel</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**Javascript code**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    document.querySelector('.submit').disabled = true;

    document.querySelector('.name').onkeyup = () => {
        // checking whether the input bar is empty or not
        if (document.querySelector('.name').value.length > 0) 
            document.querySelector('.submit').disabled = false;
        else
        document.querySelector('.submit').disabled = true;
    };

    document.querySelector('.form').onsubmit = () => {

        //Crearting a list item
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = document.querySelector('.name').value;

        //Appending it to the unordered list
        document.querySelector('.unordered').append(li);

        //Clear input feild
        document.querySelector('.name').value = '';
        document.querySelector('.submit').disabled = true;

        //Stop form from submitting
        return false;
    };
});
```

When i run this code seperately, meaning when i only run the HTML file in the webpage than the program runs perfectly (when you press the button then whatever is in the input feild, shows up as an unordered list). But when i am using the html file in a python file, it doesn't work(when i press the button the page refreshes and nothing happens)

Comment: Open up your browser console and see if you're getting a 404 anywhere (except for favicon)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onsubmit' of null
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (button.js:13)

Comment: `document.querySelector('.form').onsubmit = () => {` Your query selector is returning null

Comment: I also tried using a window.onload function. But the error is still the same

Comment: Give your form an ID and use ```document.getElementByID()```

Comment: It works now, without getElementByID(). Actually it was a typo, i had not given form a class but was referring it as .form in querySelector. But thanks for help